# How to disable xAxis crosshair snap in line numeric chart?

Tags: apexcharts

I have simple numeric chart with enabled crosshairs. yAxis crosshair does not snap to series data, xAxis crosshair snaps.
Is there any way to enable/disable snapping of xAxis/yAxis?

Series data:
[
{
"x": 0,
"y": 0
},
{
"x": 5,
"y": 5
},
{
"x": 10,
"y": 10
},
{
"x": 20,
"y": 20
},
{
"x": 40,
"y": 40
}
]

Chart options:

```
const chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    id: 'apex-line',
    type: 'line',
    toolbar: {
      tools: {
        selection: false,
        zoomin: false,
        zoomout: false
      }
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      type: 'xy',
      autoScaleYaxis: true
    }
  },
  markers: {
    size: 4,
    hover: {
      sizeOffset: 6
    }
  },
  stroke: {
    curve: 'straight'
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'numeric',
    crosshairs: {
      show: true,
      position: 'back',
      stroke: {
        color: '#b6b6b6',
        width: 1,
        dashArray: 0
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      offsetX: 0
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    show: true,
    labels: {
      show: true,
      align: 'left'
    },
    crosshairs: {
      show: true,
      position: 'back',
      stroke: {
        color: '#b6b6b6',
        width: 1,
        dashArray: 0
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      offsetX: 0
    }
  }
}
```

[image: example]